# Understanding and applying sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, information-retrieval, sentiment-analysis

I was just having been assigned a project of conducting sentiment analysis for some document collections. By Googling, a lot of sentiment-related research has popped up.

My questions are:

1. What are the major methods/algorithms for sentiment analysis in the field of machine learning and statistical analysis?
2. Are there any well-established results?
3. Are there any existing open-source software that can perform the sentiment analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [SentiStrength](http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/) which performs well compared to similar algorithms, and the associated research papers. Discussion of other tools and methods can be found [here](http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-an-online-API-for-sentiment-analysis) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104601/how-can-i-perform-sentiment-analysis-on-extracted-text-from-online-sources).

Answer (score 4):

I have the impression that much of what is being done here is *extremely* heuristic. In fact, most people seem to apply this to the <120 chars of twitter statements. Probably the results (while not being computed this way) aren't much better than counting "positive" and "negative" words with a litte position information ("A better than B" = positive for A, negative for B)

When you then see companies buying a full twitter feed (that's how many mbit per second?) and claiming to do sentiment analysis on this this seriously makes me wonder if there is any *statistical validity* here. No wonder e.g. Yahoo failed badly at predicting the preelections for South Carolina: http://www.technologyreview.com/web/39487/

People are way to proud and keen on just being *at all* able to process the amount of data, they completely seem to neglect properly validating their performance.

Sorry to be this pessimistic about the state of the art.